# How to solve "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection "

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, backend, kibana

I am building elasticsearch and kibana inside docker, I have them up but when a compose logs for elasticsearch I got this warning:

```
"WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.29.0.2:9200, remoteAddress=/172.29.0.4:54642}"`
And then the logs are not connected and displayed inside elasticsearch website, noting that the same repo is running on another server and it works correctly. I will attach the files setup if someone can help or at least try them on his side. Thanks a lot.`
```

You can find my code in the following [repo](https://github.com/ihab-hachem/Loggings.git)

And also i have the same error, and then i tried to substitute all hhtp by https and also the same thing:
Elasticsearch  | {"@timestamp":"2023-01-04T14:04:50.865Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.29.0.2:9200, remoteAddress=/172.29.0.6:55870}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[ad8fe576ac58][transport_worker][T#2]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"QDf3uC44Trqpc3FHqBuXtA","elasticsearch.node.id":"3NryPkn_R1q0n9vi7WozQw","elasticsearch.node.name":"ad8fe576ac58","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}

Answer (score 0):

@IDev have you visited the link which is present in your elastiscearch.yml file for XPack security settings? There are some properties which are disabled by default but are important in order to establish connection with Elasticsearch.

Comment: Which properties do you mean? I checked lot of configurations and it works on this way

Comment: Where and when do you get the above error ? May be you need to generate some enrollment token for your client using xpack.security.enrollment.enabled. But can't say for sure unless a clear bigger picture is provided.

Comment: I found something, when I curl to elasticsearch i got the following error, `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain` Is it possible that the ssl made this issue, i have a privekey.pem and fullchain.pem how can i use them to solve this issue

Comment: @IDev in your case, as per your es yaml, you are using auto-generation and configuration of SSL over transport and HTTP layers. So essentially you will have to use those certificates and tokens.
If you want to use your own certificates, you will have to manually configure the SSL settings as provided in the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/manually-configure-security.html

Comment: They shouldn't works? If you can see I am using them but they didn't works

Comment: How can I make my server trust elasticsearch app, in order to not get curl problem?

Comment: `xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.autoconfiguration.enabled: true

xpack.security.http.ssl:

  enabled: true

xpack.security.transport.ssl:

  enabled: true`

Just providing these few properties won't make ES understand that you will be using your own certificates for SSL. If you check the link I've shared earlier, there are lot many other properties to be set for both transport and/or http ssl including your keystore/truststore path, the passphrase and keys for server. The corresponding cert/key pair should be used for client else handshake is bound to fail.

Comment: Essentially, `xpack.security.autoconfiguration.enabled: true` will ensure that your certificates and tokens are auto-generated and ES is auto-configured for SSL. 

Although this will bring up secured ES cluster, but you need to configure your kibana and other clients as well explicitly.

Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/configuring-stack-security.html#_connect_clients_to_elasticsearch_5

Comment: I am not using my ssl yet, i still use the autogenerated one, so in your opinion i should also make the configuration for kibana and logstash to onnect to elastic?

Comment: Yes, you need to configure them with tokens or fingerprints as mentioned in the documentation.